# Sending and Recieving mails using Outlook in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

My Scenario,

Im using vb.net 2003.I Have windows application where we load mails from Outlook where it is very success ful right now. But Now my application is in one ip address(192.168.1.23) and my Inbox is in (1.33) . How can i load the mails to (.23) ip address? and it should automatically load the mails from the specified folder.

Now my appliaction will ask to pick folder and allow access to 10 minutes(we specify time to access the folder)

Comment: show some of your existing vb.net code of loading mails from outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, showing some of your existing help would help a lot. It may be as simple as modifying the location in which your application looks for the email files. This is only a guess, since I can't see any of your code, but you may be able to make this work by logging on to the machine that your application runs on, mapping a network drive to the location of the files on the computer you currently use, and then referencing the location of the files in your code as such. Then you can access the files by the mapped drive letter in your code, for example: "T:\Inbox"

However, this would be unnecessary if the machine that your application runs on already has network access to the computer that you work on.

If the machine that your application runs on already has network access to your work computer (seeing as how they appear to be in the same network), you could use something like this, for example: "\YOUR_WORK_PC_NAME\C$\EMAIL\INBOX"

I'd be glad to help further if you provide some more information.